# Magento order email change date format dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: magento, datetime

Hi i have changed before this but after update to 1.8.1 i see that the email sending to the customer for new order and invoice is still 01/26/2014.
I am digging around for so long and i cannot find a proper solution
catalog/dateformat in backend is set to day/month/year but still the order emails are sent to month/day/year.
Can somebody help?
Maybe something simple here that i cannot find or maybe i had replace a core file when e-shop was 1.7 and now i cannot remember what file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry , the locale options in backend had changed to EN/US after update. Revert it back to EN/GB and everything is ok now. Strange. Anyway i answer my question and maybe i can help somebody else ;)

So proper solution is:
System/General/Locale options switched to EN/GB
and System/Catalog/Date and time options : change to day/month/year